# VB.net SOAP Webservice small program

Tags: vb.net, web-services, soap

Hi I am trying to code a small VB.net program that will update some data on our oracle CPQ site. Basically, I have used the sample XML that is used from within the CPQ site as a test (which works directly on the site) and have ported it to a vb.net program. I keep getting an error 500 "Internal server error" at line 56 Response = Request.GetResponse()

```
    Dim Request As WebRequest
    Dim Response As WebResponse
    Dim DataStream As Stream
    Dim Reader As StreamReader
    Dim SoapByte() As Byte
    Dim SoapStr As String
    Dim pSuccess As Boolean = True


    SoapStr = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>"
    SoapStr = SoapStr & "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">"
    SoapStr = SoapStr & "<soapenv:Header/>"
    SoapStr = SoapStr & "<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse=""http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"" xmlns:wsu=""http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"">"
    SoapStr = SoapStr & "<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id=""UsernameToken-2"">"
    SoapStr = SoapStr & "<wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>"
    SoapStr = SoapStr & "<wsse:Password Type=""http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText"">password</wsse:Password>"
    SoapStr = SoapStr & "</wsse:UsernameToken>"
    SoapStr = SoapStr & "</wsse:Security>"
    SoapStr = SoapStr & "</soapenv:Header>"
    SoapStr = SoapStr & "<soapenv:Body>"
    SoapStr = SoapStr & "<bm:modifyParts xmlns:bm=""http://xmlns.oracle.com/cpqcloud/parts"">"
    SoapStr = SoapStr & "<bm:Parts>"
    SoapStr = SoapStr & "<bm:each_record>"
    SoapStr = SoapStr & "<bm:part_number>0000158-01-LIMT-MX-10</bm:part_number>"
    SoapStr = SoapStr & "<bm:description>"
    SoapStr = SoapStr & "<bm:en>OPER - SOAP Test 1</bm:en>"
    SoapStr = SoapStr & "</bm:description>"
    SoapStr = SoapStr & "</bm:each_record>"
    SoapStr = SoapStr & "</bm:Parts>"
    SoapStr = SoapStr & "</bm:modifyParts>"
    SoapStr = SoapStr & "</soapenv:Body>"
    SoapStr = SoapStr & "</soapenv:Envelope>"

    Try
        SoapByte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SoapStr)

        Request = WebRequest.Create("https://velaninctest.bigmachines.com/v2_0/receiver/parts")
        Request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "https://velaninctest.bigmachines.com/v2_0/receiver/parts")

        Request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
        Request.ContentLength = SoapByte.Length
        Request.Method = "POST"

        DataStream = Request.GetRequestStream()
        DataStream.Write(SoapByte, 0, SoapByte.Length)
        DataStream.Close()

        Response = Request.GetResponse()
        DataStream = Response.GetResponseStream()
        Reader = New StreamReader(DataStream)
        Dim SD2Request As String = Reader.ReadToEnd()

        TextBox1.Text = SD2Request

        DataStream.Close()
        Reader.Close()
        Response.Close()

    Catch ex As WebException
        MsgBox(ex.ToString())
    End Try
```

---

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. You can check the WSDL definition of the service calls available: https://velaninctest.bigmachines.com/v2_0/receiver/

[Sample from CPQ site to test SOAP call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aTkx.png)

Answer (score 0):

You've probably found it by now, but looks like you closed the "" tag on line 12 before its contents. Can't speak to the VB.net (been too long) but the CPQ Webservice call looks fine.

-Chris